# Insert via Active Record works on local, fails on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, activerecord, orm

Server fails at running the following line

```
$insert = $this->ci->db->query("INSERT INTO ".$_GET['tableName']." VALUES (DEFAULT".$_GET['values'].");");
```

I don't know how to display the errors, because the script is loaded via `xhr`. On local I have PostgreSQL 9.3.0 version, on server 8.4.13. 

It's strange, since other queries like `UPDATE` or `DELETE` work on both.

**EDIT**: It was the case of privileges. My user on server didn't have privileges on using sequences.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to specify the columns to insert into? `INSERT INTO table (column_1, column_2, etc) VALUES(1,2,etc)`

Comment: @dbh - aren't both ways acceptable?

Comment: Check the ; on the );"